# UWP access to online data (like an SQL server)

Tags: database, windows-runtime, uwp

I'm writing an app where I would like to be able to save data on an online database. However it seems that UWP does not support that. In the future I'm planning on expanding the application to Mac OSX, but I don't care about smartphones and tablets.

What I want to do is for users to create an account and save their data online so they can access it from a different computer (and cross platform). In addition to that I would like for other users to be able to upload and access (share) public data.

Can anyone here help guide me to a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Of course UWP Supports that You have to create a rest-API that is connected to a ratabase. Then you should be able to send http requests to it.